# Upload and return multiple HttpPostedFiles from server

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a simple mechanism for multiple pictures upload.

Files are being uploaded correctly to the server, but when I get some error on the server side, I do `ModelState.AddModelError("PostedPhotos", "Error msg");` and pass my viewmodel back to the view, where I want to show this error and picture previews again.

Unfortunatelly, `PostedPhotos` is `null`. Maybe I bind something in a wrong way.

In my viewmodel `PostedPhotos` is:

```
public List<HttpPostedFileBase> PostedPhotos { get; set; }
```

And in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostedPhotos, new { name = "PostedPhotos[]", type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })
}
```

Is it possible to pass my files back? I wanted to do something like a stupid workaround. I can create hidden inputs with single `HttpPostedFileBase` and then use `jQuery` to set `$(myPostedPhotosInput)[0].files = getFilesFromTrickySingleFileInputs();`, but I don't like it.

Comment: At which moment is `PostedPhotos` null, when you receive request, or when you render view for response? Also please post action code

Comment: After I receive my request back

Comment: No you cannot return the files back to the view for security reasons (and you can't use jquery either). The user needs to select the files again (but you can save the files and pass back a list of those file names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cannot return the value of file inputs using `return View()`. Nor can you set the value using jquery. Doing so would be a major security issue. Someone could create a site with multiple hidden file inputs, set the values to common file names (say C:\password.doc) and download your files without your knowledge.

If you return the view, the users needs to re-select the files. As an alternative, you could save the files when you first submit (perhaps to a temporary location) and return the file names (a view model or `ViewBag` property) so that you can notify the user that those files have been uploaded and do not need to be re-selected.